# make child elements not affect width, but affect height of a parent li?

Tags: html, css

If you have a simple 2 layer list like so:

```
<ul>

    <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub-Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub-Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub-Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Item 4</a></li>

</ul>
```

i currently have each 1st level `li` floating left and no widths have been defined (and i want to keep it that way). However if the text in a 2nd level `li` is longer than the 1st level `li` then the 1st level one will expand to the 2nd level.

How can i stop this expansion?
baring in mind the 2nd level items are block and **NOT** absolutely positioned.

Comment: Can we see your CSS? It would be helpful.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted your current CSS (maybe put your HTML and CSS on http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Sorry, i would have but it changes frequently so i was hoping for a generic solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By positioning your second level list absolutely you'll take it out of the natural flow of the document.

This will stop the first level li from expanding to accomodate the size of the second level ul

```
ul li {
  position:relative;
}
ul li ul{
  position:absolute;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ydByA/)

Comment: why is it always the simple solutions that i can't think of... - Thanks!